# How to parse a file, name of which is not known

Tags: python, file, parsing, file-io

I want to download a file from s3 using the s3cmd interface. I am using the command:

```
s3cmd get s3://db-backups/db/production_dump_2013-09-12_12-00.sql.gz dump1.sql.g
```

The command works fine. Next, I want to automate the task of downloading the file. There are multiple files with similar name in the directory differing only by the time-stamp, like:

```
production_dump_2013-09-12_09-00.sql.gz
production_dump_2013-09-12_12-00.sql.gz
production_dump_2013-09-12_15-00.sql.gz
production_dump_2013-09-12_18-00.sql.gz
production_dump_2013-09-12_21-00.sql.gz
```

How can I download the latest file? If the name of the file is known then i can use:

```
cmd = 's3cmd get s3://voylladb-backups/db/production_dump_2013-09-12_12-00.sql.gz dump1.sql.gz'
args = shlex.split(cmd)
p=subprocess.Popen(args)
p.wait()
```

How to modify this (or use some other method) to get the file with the latest time-stamp?

Thanks

Comment: take the date, format it, insert it in your command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `s3cmd ls s3://voylladb-backups/db/`.

Then assuming you get back a list, you can sort it in reverse and take the first item. This is probably not the most concise way to write this, but it should work:

```
import subprocess, re

# Use subprocess.check_output to get the output from the terminal command
lines = subprocess.check_output("s3cmd ls s3://voylladb-backups/db/".split(" ")).split("\n")

# the format is a bit weird so we want to isolate just the s3:// paths
# we'll use a regex search to find the s3:// pattern and any subsequent characters
file_re = re.compile("s3://.+")
files = []

# next we iterate over each line of output from s3cmd ls looking for the s3 paths
for line in lines:
    result = file_re.search(line)
    if result:
        # and add them to our list
        files.append(result.group(0))

# finally, reverse the list so the newest file is first, and grab the first item
files.sort(reverse=True)
print files[0] # production_dump_2013-09-12_21-00.sql.gz
```

Comment: @naka Updated to reflect getting a list from s3cmd.